# XNALaraMesh addon syntax error

Tags: add-on

I'm trying to import a model, and to do that I need the XNALaraMesh addon, and I downloaded it from this tutorial here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SRRt2gZOg_Q&t=639s

The problem is, once I download it, when I try to check the box to enable the addon, I get the following error:

[image]

I'm using blender 2.79 and I'm not sure why I'm getting this error. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Recommend consult the home page here https://github.com/johnzero7/XNALaraMesh  switch to the 2.79 branch if that is the version you wish to work with.  Post issues to the issue tracker there.

Comment: @batFINGER I downloaded the 2.79 version, but it's not even letting me install it.